# Spring Data (mongoDB), findBy proxied method on repository doesn't work with null values

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data, findby

I have a proxied method in a MongoRepository extender class like this:

```
public interface InvitationRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String>
{
    public Foo findByUserIdAndDestinationMail( String userId, String destinationMail );
}
```

When I try to find a `Foo` instance in DB without any `destinationMail` by calling:

```
Foo foo = invitationRepository.findByUserIdAndDestinationMail( userId, null );
```

`MappingMongoConverter` throws a `NullPointerException`.

¿Can I find instances with null values with any proxied method?

If I need to create the method in a custom implementation ¿how can I do this with `mongoTemplate`? ¿Is there somthing like this?

```
mongoTemplate.findOne( new Query( 
    Criteria.where( "userId" ).is( userId ).and( "destinationMail" ).is(... )),
    entityClass );
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a chance you can add the detailed stacktrace? Actually MappingMongoConverter should be able to handle null values correctly. Might be worth rather opening a JIRA inside our bug tracker. Thanks!

Comment: Oliver I'll try to reproduce the error and send de stacktrace. I have had no time for this one.

Comment: Any feedback whatsoever? If not, I am just inclined to answer: It just works ;)

Comment: I'm so sorry. I've been very busy and I'd forgotten this issue. Of course this problem doesn't appears in currents versions. Thank you.

Comment: I'll vote to remove this question.

Comment: I've added an answer to point to 1.0.1 version for the problem to be solve (if it ever existed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to appear in the current 1.0.1.RELEASE version. Thus if you face this issue, please upgrade to this version.